# postRegister not working laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to build a form and autheticate the user using built in authentication in laravel, I followed this tutorial `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqkt6eSsRZs&feature=iv&src_vid=xn2snypAcIQ&annotation_id=annotation_2749752877` but it seems mine is not redirecting into '/home'

Here is my form:

in login.blade.php (copied from documentation)

```
    <!-- resources/views/auth/login.blade.php -->

<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

register.blade.php

```
<!-- resources/views/auth/register.blade.php -->

<form method="POST" action="/auth/register">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Name
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        Confirm Password
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

route list

```
    +--------+----------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI           | Name | Action                                                | Middleware |
+--------+----------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /             |      | Closure                                               |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | auth/login    |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogin     | guest      |
|        | POST     | auth/login    |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postLogin    | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD | auth/logout   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogout    |            |
|        | POST     | auth/register |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postRegister | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD | auth/register |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getRegister  | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD | home          |      | Closure                                               |            |
+--------+----------+---------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

route.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('home', function(){
    echo "welcome home";
});

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the redirect path in the `AuthController` like so:

`protected $redirectPath = '/home';`

So in your controller this should look like:

```
//The beginning of the controller....

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    private $redirectTo = '/home';

    //The rest of the controller...
```

Check it out in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-authenticating).